# How do I automatize printing bar-code labels?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, libraries, barcode

I am trying to print barcodes for a library.  I have generated a list of sequential numbers and copied them into Word 2003.

I want Library name, barcode font, barcode number printed in an Avery 5160 label sheet.

I can get it to work by going to tools, letters and mailing, Envelopes and Labels, labels tab and type in what data I want.  I don't see how I can pull this data from the list in the word document rather than just what I type.

Comment: I ended up writing an Access application to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing an Access application to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It's easiest if your list of numbers is in a table, but it may be possible with other file formats.  Under "Letters and Mailings" choose "Mail Merge" instead of "Letters and Labels" then follow the wizard in the pane that appears on the right-hand side of your screen.

It's broken down into roughly three steps: document type (labels), data source (the file with your list of numbers) and finally inserting the fields onto your labels - then using the option to copy it to all labels on the page before doing the actual merge to get your labels.  There's a walk-through of this mail merge process on [Microsoft's Office website](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HA010349201033.aspx).

Comment: I tried using Mail Merge but it seems to just want to print names and addresses,

Comment: It will, you just need to follow the steps (make sure you're clicking "mail merge" instead of "envelopes and labels") and customise the labels with your own fields from your data source.  It is designed for mailing addresses but will work with almost any type of data, as long as it can read your source file (the file with your barcodes listed).  An Excel spreadsheet or document with a table containing the data works best.

Answer (score 1):

Put the list in Excel rather than Word.  You should be able to use an excel sheet as a datasource for your word labels.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if word can be used for such automation, and in any case you will be far better of by using a program with dedicated bar code printing support. There is a list of  [Bar Code Programs For Unix & Linux](http://www.adams1.com/unix.html) that might contain something you can use, or there is a 
[Barcode Writer in Pure PostScript](http://www.terryburton.co.uk/barcodewriter/) which should be very general, although you probably have to script a bit to make use of it. I also know of a [KBarcode](http://www.kbarcode.net/) program for KDE. For windows I do not know anything specific, but you can serach for other programs yourself.

Comment: I need somethings that works on Windows.  I have tried searching but have found nothing that just prints a sheet of consecutive barcodes.

Answer (score -1):

I use an ASP page for this type of thing. I have an ASP source that generates barcodes which is called by an ASP page or a .NET page. The coding is not small so I'm not putting it in until or unless you ask for it.
The call to this code is:

```
<IMG SRC="http://localhost/BarCode.asp?code=<%= strCode %>&height=30&width=1&mode=code39">
```

**Edit:** You can find the source on Planet Source Code here: http://www.planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=9765&lngWId=4

Comment: if it's a large script, it'd be better to link to an offsite script host anyway (eg, pastebin.ca or the like).